# Loading mysql data in automatic generated columns and rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, twitter-bootstrap, pdo

So the idea is of creating a webshop, where, in this case the information for t-shirts will be loaded into different columns and rows.
I want rows to consist of 4 columns.

I'm using the PDO method for requesting data from mysql (yes.. i used a global variable for pdo, already looked into that.)
And I'm using Bootstrap to create rows and columns.

So far I've been able to create a code that loads the data and stores it into a column. But my knowledge really seems to end here. I was hoping someone could show me a method,

where it loads the data for 4 t-shirts, stores it in these columns
then loads the data for the next 4 t-shirts and puts it in a new row with again 4 columns.

my code so far:

PDO loading data

```
<?php
global $pdo;
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // throw all errors.
try 
{
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM products"); // form the sql statement.
    $results = array(); // initialise an array for the results.
    if ($stmt->execute()) { // execute the call to the db.
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
    { // loop through the resultset.
        $results[] = $row; // load each row into the array.
    }
}
} catch (PDOException $e) 
{
    echo $e->getMessage(); // print any errors.
}

?>
```

Putting it into a column and row:

```
foreach ($results as $result) 
{ // loop through the resultset and print each row.
    echo "<div class=\"row\">\n";
    echo "<div class=\"col-xs-3\"  style=\"background-color:lavender;\">\n";
    echo "<a href=\"article.php?id=".$result['ID']."\">".$result['productname']."</a>\n";
    echo "</div>\n";
    echo "</div>\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always skip the rows:

```
foreach ($results as $result) { 
    echo "<div class=\"col-xs-3\"  style=\"background-color:lavender;\">\n";
    echo "<a href=\"article.php?id=".$result['ID']."\">".$result['productname']."</a>\n";
    echo "</div>\n";
}
?>
```

This way, it will always print out 4 columns, and will automatically overflow into the next row when it can't fit any more columns. Alternatively, use a counter to determine when to echo out a row:

```
$item = 1;
echo "<div class=\"row\">\n";
foreach ($results as $result) { 
    echo "<div class=\"col-xs-3\"  style=\"background-color:lavender;\">\n";
    echo "<a href=\"article.php?id=".$result['ID']."\">".$result['productname']."</a>\n";
    echo "</div>\n";
    if($item % 4 == 1) { // i.e. Count is divisible by 4
        echo "</div><div class=\"row\">\n"; 
    }
    $item++;
}
?>
```

Note that the first row is declared outside the loop, and every time we hit 4 items, we finish off the first row and declare a new one. My logic might be a bit off, but you get the general idea. Also look into pagination, there is a way to return only a set amount of results, but it's not something I've had to work with personally.

Good luck!

Comment: Alright thanks for the quick response! Will look into both methods and see what works best!